# How should I design an exercise study?

Tags: experiment-design, research-design

I want to design a study to investigate the efficacy of a specific training protocol. I have 20 subjects. All of the subjects will complete an initial test of a physical exercise to failure. The number of repetitions are noted as a baseline.

After the initial test, I want to compare two different training methods to see which one will provide the best endurance increase  in the subjects measured as a difference in repetitions to failure compared with the initial test.

Unfortunately I can't control what the subjects do outside of the assigned training. I suspect a lot of variance due to this.

I don't know how to set up a study in a way to measure the desired effect. I hope someone can help med with some suggestions.

Comment: "Difference between two exercise groups" does  not imply any kind of control group.  How you design the experiment depends on what kind of difference you want to investigate and how you measure it: those are the kinds of missing details it would help us to have before we can answer your question.

Comment: I am new to study design and I hope this clears up my intent. However I am not sure what to do with the statistical analysis. I hope someone can point me to a resource of knowledge.